# Debug silverlight out of browser apps by pressing play

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, out-of-browser

I want to make my startup app the silverlight application and make it run by pressing play.

The problem i have is that I use https and I need the web services to use IIS.

How can i do this?

Comment: When you use out of browser feature you must manage System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage. Beside this by right clicking silverlight project and choosing "set as startup project".

Comment: Maybe you can use MOQ library for testing and simulating.Another way you can reference from your IIS endpoint while your IIS running. If there is authentication send your Credentials also.